# Ubuntu server second network card is disabled

Tags: ubuntu, ip, network-interface, webserver, resolv.conf

I have a physical server that has two network cards. One of them is on the motherboard (card A) and the other is a new one that I added by myself (card B).
this command:

```
lshw -class network
```

show that card A is active by default, no problem there.
But card B is disabled, so I use:

```
sudo ifconfig  enp3s0 up
```

to enabling card B. (enp3s0  is Card B logical name).

After this, I just want to set a static IP for card b.
and for this purpose I used these commands:

```
ifconfig enp3s0 "My Ip" netmask 255.255.0 up
route add default gw "My Ip"
echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8"> /etc/resolve.conf
```

then I ping google, and everything is fine.
But, after a reboot Card B loose all the setting and become disabled again.

So I did some search and I did find out that I need to do some static Ip setting. I use

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

to add static IP.
and add this to interface file:

```
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet loopback
iface enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address "my ip"
netmask 255.255.255.0
gw "my ip"
dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
```

After reboot, this setting is there, but Card B is disabled again.

for sums up, my question is, how to enable second network card permanently and how to set static Ip for it?

P.S: I have some network setting so I can't reset the network.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu by default comes with netplan these days and it configures the network interfaces during the boot time.

When you restart your server, can you check file names in `/run/systemd/network/` to see if they are generated by `netplan`?

If the files were generated by netplan, add your interface config in `/etc/netplan/*.yml` and apply the changes. Then see if the interface survives a reboot.

Here is a [guide](https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/netplan-how-to-configure-static-ip-address-in-ubuntu-18-04-using-netplan.html) to set static IP using netplan.

Comment: in fact, I did this and add my interface in netplan..